# What is an unmodified hit roll?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In Warhammer 40k 8th Edition, Orks commonly have an ability called *"Dakka! Dakka! Dakka!"*. The rule reads:

> Each time you roll an unmodified hit roll of 6 with a ranged weapon made by this model, that hit roll succeeds regardless of any modifiers. *[...]*

I am very confused by the wording, and don't exactly know how to apply it. Imagine I have an Ork with this ability and a ballistic skill of 5+, and they would fire eight shots at an enemy unit. The dice return as follows:

> 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 6

Since no modifiers were applied, to me this seems like an "unmodified hit roll", and three hits would be counted, out of which two (the 6's) would be affected by *"Dakka! Dakka! Dakka!"*. Is this understanding correct?

Now imagine that the weapon my Ork was affected by some ability that would allow them to add +1 to their hit rolls. If the same dice result would come up, it would now result in 4 hits, but none of those hits would be affected by *"Dakka! Dakka Dakka!"*. Is this understanding correct?

And if so, would that mean that, for the sake of *"Dakka! Dakka! Dakka!"*, every "buff" to my hit rolls would actually disable this very useful skill?

Comment: Not a 40k player, but I believe it means that for the purposes of Dakka you look at the number as rolled and check whether it was a 6. Then for any other purpose, you apply the modifiers as required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*Dakka! Dakka! Dakka!*" will still apply to the 2 "*natural*" 6s.

The wording can be a little confusing, but Warhammer uses "*unmodified hit rolls of 6*" and "*hit rolls of 6 before modifiers are applied*" interchangeably.

Essentially it only cares about the number showing on the dice and doesn't pay attention to modifiers being applied.

The place this is most clearly set out is in the [Designers Commentary](https://www.warhammer-community.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Warhammer_40000_Designers_Commentary.pdf)

Comment: Alright, I see. I wish there was a more concise wording to refer to the natural die result.

Comment: This is important because it means that you can't apply modifiers to get better benefit from Dakka Dakka Dakka, but also your opponent can't apply modifiers to take it away from you! You'll also see many abilities that trigger off an unmodified roll of 1.

Comment: @aslum I was more worried that "an unmodified hit roll" would mean "As soon as there *are* modifiers, you would lose out on the effect".

Comment: Understandable. GW doesn't exactly have a reputation for well written rules.